# What is the highest velocity a spacecraft has left Earth?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, record

The comment below [@TomSpilker's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38609/12102)

> I'd love to see anything in LEO that can impart 20.89km/s of delta V to anything.

got me wondering what the highest velocity a spacecraft has left the Earth, relative to Earth?

This could be expressed as $v_{\infty}$ km/s or $C_3$ (km^2/s^2) relative to Earth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That would be the [New Horizons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons) spacecraft, launched to a V-infinity of 16.26 km/s, with a *monumental* propulsion effort. The article describes the launch vehicle. Not only did it use a big Atlas V 551 with an expensive, high-performance Centaur upper stage, it had a *third* stage: an ATK Star 48B, a huge addition considering the New Horizons spacecraft weighed in at only 478 kg at launch.

Comment: Excellent, and illustrates that (roughly speaking) it's harder to get to the Sun than to Pluto.

Comment: [New Horiiiiiiiizzohohons...](https://youtu.be/j3Jm5POCAj8)

Comment: Okay, this one's right up your alley; [What do all these vectors point to in this New Horizons trajectory/operations simulation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38633/12102)