# What is this block of long, skinny rectangles in this New Horizons trajectory/operations simulation?

Tags: attitude, mission-design, software, new-horizons, attitude-determination-and-control

[This answer to *What do all these vectors point to in this New Horizons trajectory/operations simulation?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38669/12102) begins:

> The software is definitely AGI's STK (notice the font and the states at the left top corner). There seem to be two or maybe three frames attached to the spacecraft.

[image: Sir Brian May's New Horizons music video and probably AGI's STK graphics]

Also shown are a block of long, skinny rectangles drawn against the celestial sphere, and these move around as the spacecraft's attitude changes.

**Question:** What is this block of long, skinny rectangles in this New Horizons trajectory/operations simulation?

---

[image: Sir Brian May's New Horizons music video and probably AGI's STK graphics] [image: Sir Brian May's New Horizons music video and probably AGI's STK graphics]
[image: Sir Brian May's New Horizons music video and probably AGI's STK graphics] [image: Sir Brian May's New Horizons music video and probably AGI's STK graphics]

#### Lower your volume before playing!

Video cued at `02:30`; there is loud music at this point

Comment: Possibly an undesirable effect of the 3D rendering process.

Comment: @Fred whatever it is, it seems to be opposite the RTG and rotate along with the spacecraft. It also turns out that [LORRI is opposite the RTG and rotates along with the spacecraft](https://pluto.jhuapl.edu/Mission/Spacecraft.php). *Coincidence?*

Comment: My system is having problems with that link: *The connection has timed out

The server at pluto.jhuapl.edu is taking too long to respond*.

Comment: @Fred ya it's timing out for me also now, but it worked fine an hour ago. **update:** it's suddenly working for me now, but here's an image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv0om.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like the instrument fields-of-view (FOVs).

Figure 7 of [The New Horizons Spacecraft, Fountain et al.](https://www.boulder.swri.edu/pkb/ssr/ssr-fountain.pdf) looks quite similar:

[image: New Horizons instruments]

Comment: *They sure do!* The instruments can't independently point themselves; their FOVs are permanently glued to the spacecraft's attitude.