# If a spaceship were to lose all fuel, where does it go?

Tags: gravity, physics

If a spaceship were to run out of fuel mid-flight, and it was between two solar systems, one with 2 suns and 6 planets, and one with 1 star and 10 planets, where does it go? I feel like I’m missing something knowledgeable here.

Comment: Would this help https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38988/if-a-spaceship-ran-out-of-fuel-somewhere-in-space-between-earth-and-mars-does-i/38991#38991

Answer (score 5):

Since a spaceship doesn't really burn much fuel during its voyage, except for at the start, at the end, and for any trajectory correction maneuvers in between, it doesn't really matter whether or not it has fuel for the most part of its flight.

In other words, if it loses its fuel mid-flight, it would likely end up close to where it would have ended up if it *hadn't* lost its fuel, but *when* it ends up there, it won't have any way of changing its course or braking.